# Proving a linear transform defined by an integral is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials

Let the fact that $I(p)(x)=\int_0^x p(s) ds$ is a linear transform from $P_4\rightarrow P_5$ be given.
Prove that $I$ is injective.

Would it be sufficient to just state that for any 2 polynomials,$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ $\in$ $P_4$ such that if $(I)(f)(x)=(I)(g)(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$, then $f(x)=g(x)$?
I am not sure if I have to use the fact that since $I$ is a linear transform, $(I)(f)(x)-(I)(g)(x)=(I)(f-g)(x)=0$. I feel like I am oversimplifying this problem or I am missing some important step.

Comment: see here as well: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867516/surjective-but-not-injective-linear-transformation

Answer (score 2):

In the first paragraph you really mean "injective".

There is no poblem with your approach, though it might turn out to be at bit lengthy if you don't use linearity beforehand.

Alternatively, use that $\frac{d}{dx}\circ I=\mathrm {id}$. This shows injectivity immediately.

Comment: How would I incorporate linearity into my approach? I know that I would state that since $I$ is linear, it adheres to the property of additivity. I am not entirely sure how to use the fact that $(I)(f)(x)-(I)(g)(x)=(I)(f-g)(x)=0$ to support my claim.

Comment: @user3699546 usually you want to wait a bit before accepting an answer, in order to get more response from users of this site